# Button changed size for some unexplained reason

Tags: html, css

You can see the button in question at the bottom of the page (it's just a link styled to look like a button). What is causing it to extend upwards? I previously had it styled to look the way that I wanted, but at some point something caused it to go haywire.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Reset */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

/* End CSS Reset */






@charset "utf-8";
/* General Styles */

body {
    max-width: 100%; 
    margin: 0;   
    font-size: 16px;   
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;  
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;   
    color: #555; 
}

p {
 text-align: center; 
}

/* Nav Bar Styles */

nav {
    text-align: right;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #fff; 
 font-size: 1.4em;
 padding: 0;
 padding-top: .5%;
 padding-bottom: .6%;  
}

.navigation {
    display: inline;
    margin: .5%;
  
}

.logo {
 color:#000; 
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 0 0 1%;
}

/* Banner */

div.background {
 margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
 min-height: 650px;
 background-image: url("../img/br.jpg");
 background-sizeP: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat; 
 
}

/* Skills */

div.section {
 width: 100%; 
 min-height: 200px;
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #000;
 margin: 0;  
}

.skills {
 float: left;
 width: 33%; 
}

.expertise {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 2% 2% 2% 2%;
 font-size: 1.2em; 
}

.details {
 padding: 2%; 
}



/* Footer */

footer {
    text-align: center;
 padding-bottom: .4%;  
    margin: 0;
 font-size: 79%;
 color: #000;
 background-color: #fff;     
}

a.btn {
   width: 11%;
   margin: auto;
   margin-top: .8%;
   padding: .5%;
   display: block;
   text-align: center; 
   border: 1px solid #fff;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   background-color: #000;
   color: #fff;
   border-radius: 3px;   
}

.btn:hover {
 
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
 border: solid 1px #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Brian Funderburke Photography &amp; Design</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<header>
  
    <nav>
        <h1 class="logo">B.Fun Photography &amp; Design</h1>
            <ul>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="photography.html">Photography</a></li>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="design.html">Design</a></li>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
    
</header>

<div class="background">

</div>

<div class="section">
    <div class="skills">
        <h2 class="expertise">Photography</h2>
            <p class="details">Let me capture your beautiful moments for you! I shoot everything from weddings to landscapes.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="skills">
        <h2 class="expertise">Design</h2>
            <p class="details">From logo design to business cards. Your products deserve to look beautiful.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="skills">
        <h2 class="expertise">Web Development</h2>
            <p class="details">Handcrafted websites help ensure you stand out in today's crowded online ecosystem!</p>
    </div>
    <a href="contact.html" class="btn">Get In Touch!</a>
</div>

<footer>
    <p>&#169; 2016 Brian Funderburke. All Rights Reserved.</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is "display: block" which is making it take up the entire container of ".section". Try removing the width and you will see it more clearly. (As to why the text is at the bottom, it is because you have "vertical-align: baseline". It is as tall as it is because the other elements are floated in the container, so it is pushed below them.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It fixed the issue :)

Comment: No problem @bfunphoto - Can you mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem?

Comment: sure thing! Wasn't sure how to do that before you brought it up, but I'll start doing it more often now.